# Switch statement for category selection and output

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I have this part in my code, where I will have to create like 14 `if/else` conditionals, so I wanted to see if someone knows a better way for me to handle a Image render with multiple conditions.

So this is what I have:

```
if placeC.places[0].category == "Route" {
    Image("map-pin")
        .renderingMode(.template)
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
        .foregroundColor(placeC.places[0].show ? .red : Color.init(UIColor(hexString: "#6A798E")))
        .onTapGesture {
            if !placeC.places[0].show {
                tapOnMapAnnotation(
                    place: placeC.places[0]
                )
            }
        }
        .overlay(
            Awesome.Image(icon: Awesome.Solid.route)
                .size(12)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(.bottom, 15)
        )
} else if placeC.places[0].category == "Scenic Area" {
    Image("map-pin")
        .renderingMode(.template)
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
        .foregroundColor(placeC.places[0].show ? .red : Color.init(UIColor(hexString: "#006994")))
        .onTapGesture {
            if !placeC.places[0].show {
                tapOnMapAnnotation(
                    place: placeC.places[0]
                )
            }
        }
        .overlay(
            Awesome.Image(icon: Awesome.Solid.binoculars)
                .size(12)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(.bottom, 15)
        )
     etc...
```

Everything is the same, except the category and the `hexString: "----"` - How would I be able to utilize a function or possible a switch statement on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can abstract it into

```
func hexStringForCategory(_ category: String) -> String {
  switch category {
    case "Route":
      return "#6A798E"
    case "Scenic Area":
      return "_DIFFERENT_COLOR_"
    //etc..
    default:
      return "#FFFFFF"
  }
}

@ViewBuilder func viewForPlace(_ place: Place) -> some View {
  Image("map-pin")
        .renderingMode(.template)
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
        .foregroundColor(place.show ? .red : Color.init(UIColor(hexString: hexStringForCategory(place.category))))
        .onTapGesture {
            if !place.show {
                tapOnMapAnnotation(
                    place: place
                )
            }
        }
        .overlay(
            Awesome.Image(icon: Awesome.Solid.route)
                .size(12)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(.bottom, 15)
        )
}
```

Then, you could just call:

```
viewForPlace(placeC.places[0])
```

If you're only ever going to do this for `placeC.places[0]`, you don't even need the second function -- you can just use the first.

Comment: This is awesome! It works so well!